# How to add the elements in Object[] class variable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to add the elements in `Object[]` class variable? I've `arrayList` object which contain DTO class data (row 125, columns 6). I would like to display the all data in `JTable`.

```
String[] columnNames = {"TEST CASE NUMBER", "NO OF EXECUTION", "TOTAL NO OF PASSED", "TOTAL NO OF FAILED", "FINAL RESULT", "DATE & TIME"};

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);  

for (Object item : arrayList) {
    Object[] row = new Object[6];

    how to add the element in row ...?

    model.addRow(row);
}
final JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Comment: What are the expected values come from `arrayList`?  Do you know the class type?  How do you access the DTO's properties?

Answer (score 0):

you can maintain an integer *`i`* and in loop you can do

```
row [i] = item ;
```

P.S you have to check `null`,`length` etc to avoid `exceptions` ...

Comment: it is not working table is blank but in consule Ouput-ROW DATA automationtool.Resultset@34b0ede5
ROW DATA automationtool.Resultset@34b0ede5 when i made changes in code for (Object item : list) {
                Object[] row = new Object[6];
                for(int i=0; i<6;i++){
                   
                    row [i] = item ;   
                    System.out.println("ROW DATA "+row [i]);
                }
                model.addRow(row);
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] row = new Object[number_of_element];

for(int i = 0; i < number_of_object; i++)
    row[i] = (Object)item;
```

Also, be careful that you are creating row array inside for loop, it should be outside the loop

Comment: OUTPUT is : -[Ljava.lang.Object;@5374a6e2
OUTPUT : -[Ljava.lang.Object;@f786a3c and Table is blank

Comment: your table is blank, so this error is normal. If your table is blank then `number_of_element` is 0. Then no exception or no error.